# Using Office 365 SharePoint REST API within Rails app, access token fails

Tags: rest, ruby-on-rails-4, ms-office, sharepoint-2013, office365

I'm trying to use an Office 365 organizational SharePoint site as a storage point through the SharePoint REST API for docx files generated in a Rails app. I've registered the app through `https://<domain>.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appregnex.aspx` and obtained a client_id and client_secret. Using `https://<domain>.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx`, I gave the app the following permissions:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

Using the oauth2 gem, I've so far managed to obtain an access token using client_credentials:

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new(<client_id>, <client_secret>, site: "https://<domain>.sharepoint.com", token_url: "https://login.windows.net/<tenant_id>/oauth2/token")
token = client.get_token(grant_type: "client_credentials", client_id: client.id, client_secret: client.secret, resource: "https://<domain>.sharepoint.com")
```

The client_credentials strategy seems to work, as a token is received. However, trying to use it results in failure.

`token.get("/_api/web/title")` returns `OAuth2::Error: { "error_description" : "The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error. For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs." }`

`RestClient.get("https://<domain>.sharepoint.com/_api/web/title", { "Authorization" => token.token })` returns `RestClient::Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized`

I'm pretty much at my wits' end over this, and I'm *this* close to telling my boss that if it can somehow be done, I'm simply not knowledgeable enough to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults` is a wcf service setting in the endpoint applications web.config. If you have access to the server https://.sharepoint.com then you can turn that on momentarily. Basically, this will send the exception trace dump to the client in the response. By default, any 500 status errors will come back with no information except for ...ooops an error occurred.

I don't know how that server is configured or that much about SharePoint at all. However, the error could be anything imaginable and not even related to oauth. Unless you can get the server log or have it spit back the exception then you are going to be spinning your wheels.

Comment: What @EugenioPace said, I don't think I can alter much since it's a SharePoint Online server rather than an on-premise installation.

Answer (score 0):

Very likely you don't have sufficient permissions. Try with different scopes.

Comment: (Let me preface this by saying how much I just love MSDN documentation.) I just tried giving FullControl AppOnly permissions on `http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web` and `http://sharepoint/content/tenant`, and just for kicks, I added https versions as well. No dice. If there are other permission scopes that can be added, I haven't been able to find documentation for it.

Comment: I hear you :-( I don't have the sample with me to double check. I can't remember exactly, but I remember having the same (or very similar) issue.